# Using crockpot for a soap making project?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

Preamble to my question:

I was told by someone at Star-K that since soap is not food, it really doesn't even need a hechsher. For example, he told me that even though Brillo pads are not kosher, it doesn't matter, even if Brillo uses a beef tallow as the soap stablizer. From the [FAQ page of brillo.com](http://brillo.com/faqs.asp):

> Q. Do Brillo Steel Wool Soap Pads contain animal products?
>   A. Yes, the soap in Brillo Steel Wool Soap Pads is made from natural beef tallow.

With that preamble, my question is: could I, [l'chat'chilah](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323), use my crock pot for a soap making project with my kids.

I would take leftover bars of soap and melt them down using the slow heat of the crock pot and then set them in molds to make new bars of soap.

(I haven't done anything yet. I'm too afraid in case the answer is no. I don't want to treif anything up.)

Comment: I'm uncertain if your assumption is correct, here. Soap, in itself, is, indeed non-food. However, In a conversation I had with a mashgiach a while ago, he said that any item that touches food does need to be kosher. This explains why dishwashing soap and aluminum foil requires a hechsher. (Some said plastic-ware and paper plates, as well.) I'll see if I can locate an article about this.

Comment: DanF, thanks for getting back. As I mentioned, someone on the Star-K consumer line told me that soap doesn't really need a hechsher. I was stunned. I had been asking him about Brillo pads and as mentioned in the post, Brillo Pad openly state on their site that they have beef tallow.

Comment: Is this a CYOR question?

Comment: @DanF, I had to VTC, as it does seem as if he is asking for a practical p'sak

Comment: Thank you everyone for quotes and sources. Sigh, even though it seems there are some room to be meikel, there seems to be enough concern not to do it.

I guess I will have to find another way to do this soap making project.

Thank you again, everyone.

PS: how could this question be off topic? I am trying to find out the practical halachic effects of putting probably not-kosher bar/bath soap into a cholent pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the [OU](https://oukosher.org/faqs/dishwashing-detergent/) regarding dishwashing soap.

> Do dishwashing detergents require kosher supervision?
>
> It is generally assumed that dishwashing detergents are not edible
> entities, and halachically they do not have a non-kosher status, even
> if they contain non-kosher ingredients, as is often the case.
> Nonetheless, some Poskim maintain that it has been the established
> minhag Yisroel (Jewish custom) to use kosher detergents on plates,
> pots and utensils that come in contact with food. An OU on a detergent
> insures the kosher status of that product. That said, if one used
> non-certified dishwashing detergent, Bidieved (after the fact), the
> kosher status of the utensils would not be compromised.

OTOH, in [this COR video](http://cor.ca/view/465/questionscor_video_does_dish_soap_require_kosher_certification.html), the rabbi concurs that it is preferable to use kosher soap, however, COR's policy is that this is unnecessary, because, the concern of non-kosher iteme applies with reference to its taste, and since soap is non-food, there is no concern regarding any non-kosher ingredients.

FWIW, when I was young, if I spoke meanly, my mom and grandma would occasionally wash out my mouth with soap. Soap was commonly made from tallow years ago. I doubt, though, that they were feeding me non-kosher "food" (Soap tastes a lot worse than the foul comment I made about my mom's food :-)

In short, the common custom is to use kosher soap, but it's unclear about what happens if you intentionally don't follow the common custom.

I recommend CYOR, and either way, good luck with your sudsy experiment :-)

Comment: Based on the OU's analysis, you would be making that pot non-kosher ≠ That said, if one used non-certified dishwashing detergent, Bidieved (after the fact), the kosher status of the utensils would not be compromised.

Comment: I'm confused. How would that make the pot non-kosher based on the OU's analysis? Are you somehow arguing that the kosher status of your utensils depends on your intentions when you did a particular action? Your quote from the OU says _l'chatchila_ you shouldn't use un-hechshered soap. How do you get from that to "if you use un-hechshered soap _l'chatchila_, your pots are no longer kosher"?

Comment: @Daniel What did you misunderstand, or have I missed? OU says that lechatchila, you should not use non-kosher soap. So, yes, it IS based on your intention, as I understand it. If you intentionally put non-kosher soap in your pot as OP suggests, you would be making your pot non-kosher. If, you put in the soap and later discovered that the soap was non-kosher, then the pot is still kosher. That's my understanding of what OU states. Did I miss it?

Comment: I don't see the OU saying anything about soap ever making something non-kosher. As @user6591 mentioned, shouldn't do it ≠ treifs up your pot. In fact, the OU doesn't even really go all the way to saying that you shouldn't do it _l'chatchila_ (although they admittedly come pretty close to saying that)

Comment: @Daniel Ah! You are more analytical than I, here. I re-read it more carefully, and you are correct. They make a recommendation, but don't seem to take a stance either way, themselves. I will edit my answer.

Comment: DanF from that last comment of yours I see the need to clarify the issue. A tasty food which is assur may not be mixed into kosher lichatchila even when less than 60x. If done intentionally, we give a fine and he may not partake of it even if it is now battul. Soap is different. It is pagum and never assurs. There is no fine for adding it. In fact I assume this OU ruling is influenced this way due to Rabbi Belsky's personal opinion of not using toothpaste with glycerin (something almost all nonhasidic poskim allow) And his personal practice of using kosher body soap in accordance with the Gra

Comment: @Daniel^^^^^^ just so you don't miss out on the conversation:)

Comment: @user6591 This is an aspect that I am unfamiliar with, so I can't fairly comment. I recommend that you condense and edit your comment to the end of my answer, if possible. If you can find a link to Rav Belsky's opinion, include it, as well.